# how to check if thread is running or waiting in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i have a thread that i want to know when the wait method is running. and when the thread is running

here is my code:

```
    runnableClass rc = new runnableClass();
    Object PauseTHR = new Object();
    boolean pause = false;
    public class runnableClass implements Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                // here is my code,after my code i want to wait thread
                // so i call onpause();
                    onpause();  
                    synchronized (PauseTHR) {
                        while(pause) {
                            Log.i("while loop", "it goes over me");
                            try {
                                PauseTHR.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            public void onpause() {
                synchronized (PauseTHR) {
                    Log.i("synchronized", "it goes over me");
                    pause = true;
                }
            }

            public void onresume() {
                synchronized (PauseTHR) {
                    pause = false;
                    PauseTHR.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
```

i set my boolean(pause) variable as global but when i check

```
if(pause == true) 
    rc.onresume();
```

out of my Runnable class it seems doesn't work and my condition works
how can i check when my thread is waiting and when my thread is runnig ??

Answer (score 3):

check your thread is alive or not by this code:

```
thread1.isAlive()
```

it returns a boolean. Returns true if the receiver has already been started and still runs code (hasn't died yet). Returns false either if the receiver hasn't been started yet or if it has already started and run to completion and died.

Comment: By the time the method returns, the info is stale.

Answer (score 3):

Use Thread.getState() method

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html

A thread can be in one of the following states:

NEW, RUNNABLE, BLOCKED, WAITING, TIMED_WAITING, TERMINATED

Comment: By the time the method returns, the info is stale.

Comment: yes ,i think it is, because when i check the thread with isAlive() or thread.getState() it doesn't work,  from your perspective what should i do to find out when my thread is waiting

Comment: use breakpoint and debug it to see what they return. ckeck this out and tell me the result